# Create file using fstream if it doesn't exist that utilizes seekp/seekg?

Tags: c++, fstream, seekg

```
fstream file(file_1.c_str(), ios::out | ios::in | ios::ate); //convert string to const char*
```

Error if File does not exist. `if ( ! file ) = true`

```
fstream file(file_1.c_str(), ios::out | ios::in | ios::app); //convert string to const char*
```

using `ios::app` `seekg` & `seekp` functions not working. `file.seekg(4, ios_base::beg);`

I would like to have:

1. USER input file name
2. create file if NON existing
3. use seekg & seekp;
4. Not remove the file if you run the program again.

Comment: What does seeking have to do with opening a file if it doesn't exist? What's the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    string name;
    std::cin>>name;
    std::ofstream file (name.c_str());
    outfile << "Text in file." << std::endl;
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```